# Tried to apply what I've learned to build snake game python but it doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle, textmate, curses

I've been trying to apply what I've learned so far following this video but it doesn't seem to work, why?

This's the video's link.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbasThWVb-c&t=8s

And this is the code I wrote to run it.

```
import random
import curses





s = curses.initscr()
curses.curs_set(0)
sh, sw = s.getmaxyx()
w = curses.newwin(sh,sw, 0,0)
w.keypad(1)
w.timeout(100)

snk_x = sw/4
snk_y =sh/2

snake = [
    [snk_y, snk_x],
    [snk_y,snk_x-1],
    [snk_y,snk_x-2]
]

food = [sh/2,sw/2]

w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)

key = curses.KEY_RIGHT


while True:
    next_key = w.getch()
    key = key if next_key == -1 else next_key

    if snake[0][0] in [0,sh] or snake[0][1] in [0,sw] or snake[0] in snake[1:]:
        curses.endwin()
        quit()

    new_head = [snake[0][0], snake[0][1]]


    if key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
        new_head[0]+=1
    if key == curses.KEY_UP:
        new_head[0]-=1
    if key == curses.KEY_LEFT:
        new_head[1]-=1
    if key == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
        new_head[1]+=1

    snake.insert(0, new_head)

    if snake[0] == food:
        food = None
        while food is None
            nf = [
                random.randint(1,sh-1)
                random.randint(1,sw-1)
            ]

            food = nf if nf not in snake else None
        w.addch(food[0],food[1], curses.ACS_PI)
     else:
         tail = snake.pop()
         w.addch(tail[0],tail[1,],' ')
     w.addch(snake[0][0],snake[0][1], curses.ACS_CKBOARD)
```

By the way, I'm using TextMate 3 editor on Mac OS and trying to run it on IDLE as you see below in the picture.[image]

Comment: Your edit shows that you have a syntax error on the line that is makred with red. Your line is missing a colon `:`

Comment: Yes, @KasemAlsharaa was right. Your `while food is None` line is missing a colon. Always add a colon (`:`) in Python right before indentation when starting an `if`, `while`, `for`, etc.

Comment: After you fix syntax errors, I believe you should run your curses code directly with python.exe.  Curses expects to talk to a simulated terminal program, while the IDLE shell is a tkinter gui program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your lines is missing a colon `:`.
You were also missing commas `,` between your `nf` list variables.

```
   if snake[0] == food:
        food = None
        while food is None:
#Here                     ^
            nf = [
                random.randint(1,sh-1),
#                                     ^
                random.randint(1,sw-1),
#                                     ^
            ]
```

Additionally, your final `else:` block was not correctly indented
You had an extra space on all lines.

```
else:
        tail = snake.pop()
        w.addch(tail[0],tail[1,],' ')
    w.addch(snake[0][0],snake[0][1], curses.ACS_CKBOARD)
```

Indents (spaces / tabs) are critical in python so that the Python interpreter understands your code blocks and so that it executes correctly

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Now I got this message as you see in this pic https://ibb.co/XD2L5DH

Comment: I found out that I need another terminal such as https://iterm2.com/ in order to work on Mac OS because Mac default terminal doesn't enable Python curses to work and function normally.